# How to force HTTPS without using .htaccess file in cPanel

Tags: php, .htaccess, ssl, https

Recently I installed SSL. It works fine , but my site doesn't redirect to https. My server isn't supporting htaccess file. Is there any other way to do this??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: in php file which loads very first by checking `$_SERVER['HTTPS']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This trick once. I am not sure its going right way. Try it and let me know.

```
<?php

if ( $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == "" )
{
    header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
    header('Location: https://yoursite.com.php');
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Now you can do  your httpd.conf file or the file where your virtual host is specified and add these lines to redirect http to https:

```
<virtualhost *:80="">

ServerName mysite.com
ServerAlias www.mysite.com
Redirect / https://<your site name>/
DocumentRoot /var/www/public_html
</virtualhost>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use in if condition

```
$_SERVER[REQUEST_SCHEME]!='https'
```